# How to auto-size an Image based on the size of a string?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, bitmap, gdi+

Is there a way to automatically fill a rectangle based on the width of string?
Currently, I am manually setting up the sizes and point of the rectangle based on the string.

```
Public Class test
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        NavButton3.Glyph = ImgNotif(NavButton3.Glyph, "99") ' My image size is 32 x 32
    End Sub

    Private Function ImgNotif(srcImg As Image, num As String) As Image
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(srcImg)
        Dim rect As New Rectangle(16, 16, 16, 16)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.OrangeRed, rect)
            g.DrawString(num, Me.Font, Brushes.White, New Point(16, 16))
        End Using
        Return bmp
    End Function
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: The `Graphics` object you're using to draw there has a `MeasureString` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your `ImgNotif()` method  to include the measure of the string.
[`Graphics.MeasureString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/403ezxd2(v=vs.110).aspx) is the directly available tool, since you have already a Graphics context derived from the Image.

[TextRederer.MeasureText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext(v=vs.110).aspx) can also be used to perform this task.

[StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to setup some formatting options: alignment, text wrapping and clipping etc. (see the documentation).

Here, the text is centered on the Image.

```
Private Function ImgNotif(sourceImage As Image, imageText As String) As Image
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(sourceImage)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Dim format As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap)
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        Dim TextSize As SizeF = g.MeasureString(imageText, Me.Font, sourceImage.Size, format)
        Dim TextLocation As PointF = New PointF((sourceImage.Width - TextSize.Width) / 2 + 1, (sourceImage.Height - TextSize.Height) / 2 + 1)
        Dim rect As New RectangleF(TextLocation, TextSize)
        rect.Inflate(0, 1)
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.OrangeRed, rect)
        g.DrawString(imageText, Me.Font, Brushes.White, rect, format)
    End Using
    Return bmp
End Function
```

Comment: Just what I need. Thanks!